# start-stop-daemon returning always 0 (success)

Tags: shell-script, init-script, lsb, start-stop-daemon

I have set up `start-stop-daemon` to start my script automatically

```
case "$1" in
   start)
      log_begin_msg "starting foo"
      start-stop-daemon --start --chuid nobody --user nobody --pidfile \
      /tmp/foo.pid --startas /usr/local/bin/foo.sh &
      log_end_msg $?
```

the problem is, it always returns 0 (success),even if the process was not started.

How can I capture the return code of `start-stop-daemon` properly ?

Comment: it seems `start-stop-deamon` returns `0` if the requested action was performed (note that it's not on if the process started). You can add some logic and use `pidof` to match `pid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not** capturing return code of `start-stop-daemon`.

Your problem is that you are launching it in the background and it is started properly. I mean that you are capturing return code of *`starting something in background that wants to start something in background`*.

Try this:

```
rm /tmp/not_existent_file &
echo $?
```

This always prints `0`.

In order to get the return code of a backgrounded process, you must wait for it to exit with `wait`. Here is an example:

```
rm /tmp/not_existent_file &
wait $!
echo $?
```

If you want to start process that is not forking on its own, try to use `--background` switch and remove `&` from the end of `start-stop-daemon` line.

See [start-stop-deamon manpage](http://man.cx/start-stop-daemon)

Comment: Thanks @jordanm for completing my answer. I forgot on the `wait` command.

Comment: when I add `wait $!` as suggested by you, then the `start-stop-daemon` never finishes. i.e. when I do `service foo start` it waits indefinitely.

Comment: Read the answer properly. The `wait` command is there only for illustration how to get return code of backgrounded process. Use `--background` switch instead.